# How to record multiple clicks while holding shift (or any other button) using Coded UI Tests?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I have a grid-component which has a multiple-column-sort feature. The multi-column-sort feature is activated by:

1. Press and hold shift key
2. Click two or more columns (while holding the shift-key)
3. Release the shift key -> Multiple sort is activated

I tried to record this using coded-ui-tests but the recording was like this:

1. Shift press and hold 1 + Click on column 1
2. Shift press and hold 2 + Click on column 2

So the coded ui test builder does not seem to grasp that I'm actually holding the shift-button. Has anyone had a similar problem? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
Keyboard.PressModifierKeys(ModifierKeys.SHIFT);
Mouse.Click
Mouse.Click
Keyboard.ReleaseModifierKeys(ModifierKeys.SHIFT);
```

PressModifierKeys: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.keyboard.pressmodifierkeys.aspx

ReleaseModifierKeys: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.keyboard.releasemodifierkeys.aspx